# Getting summarized values from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing database, one of the main targets is calculation some data.
Just for example, we have two connected tables:

- `projects` (`prid`, `prname`)
- `jobs` (`jbid`, `jbprojectid`, `jbname`, `jbhours`)

Project has jobs with some hours. Purpose is take summary jobs hours for project and use this value for other calculations. What I do now is create query like this:

```
SELECT
    projects.*,
    projecttotalhours.*
FROM
    projects
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        jobs.jbprojectid,
        SUM(jobs.jbhours) AS jbtotalhours
     FROM
        jobs
     GROUP BY
        jobs.jbprojectid
     ) AS projecttotalhours
ON
    projects.prid=projecttotalhours.jbprojectid
```

It's just simple example, real query is big enough with about twenty parameters, calculating based on `jbtotalhours` and others similar parameters. So, I don't want dynamic query for this, I want `jbtotalhours` be in `projects` table. User modify `jobs` table and `jbtotalhours` in `projects` automatically update. First, I thought about triggers: create store function (something like `gettotalhours(projectid)`) and call it in trigger. But is there any other options for that? I will use `MySQL 5.7`.

If using triggers is the only option, so is it safe enough for this task? Could data be compromised if something goes wrong? Can I defend from that?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use triggers, you can use one of these options

1. **Views**, summation in views is very dynamic and the best choice for you.
2. **Sub queries**, every statement executes for every record in master table on the fly .
3. **Common Table Expression (CTE)**, every statement or query produces a temporary result or relation. A common table expression or CTE is used to name those temporary results set that exist within the execution scope of that particular statement.

sample of sub query:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT SUM(jbhours) from jobs J where p.prid = J.jbprojectid) AS jbtotalhours
FROM projects P
```

sample of CTE:

```
WITH project_job_hours AS (  
    SELECT
    projects.*,
    projecttotalhours.*
FROM
    projects
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        jobs.jbprojectid,
        SUM(jobs.jbhours) AS jbtotalhours
     FROM
        jobs
     GROUP BY
        jobs.jbprojectid
     ) AS projecttotalhours
ON
    projects.prid=projecttotalhours.jbprojectid   
    )   
    SELECT * FROM project_job_hours 
    WHERE jbtotalhours >= 32 ORDER BY jbprojectid;
```

you can select, update, delete any other data from cte results.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just create a view?

```
create view v_projecthours as
    <your query here>;
```

Then you won't have to worry about the data getting out-of-synch.

Transferring business logic from a SQL query (which is set based) to a trigger (which is more procedural) can be tricky.  A view allows you to just take your current logic and make is widely available.